# pop up rather than down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to change this code so i can make this pop up rather than pop down?

i need this to work on a mobile at the base of a page or unless anyone else has a better solution im open to suggestions

Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
   // Clickable Dropdown
   $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
   $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
   $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
     $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
     $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }
   });
  });
```

```css
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/

*,
*:after,
*:before {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 font-smoothing:antialiased;
 text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}
body {
 font:400 13px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 background:#333;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    STRUCTURE
\*------------------------------------*/

.wrapper {
 max-width:1280px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.header {
 padding:15px 25px;
 background:#FFF;
 border-left:5px solid #2BA6CB;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.logo {
 float:left;
}
.nav {
 float:right;
 margin:12px 0;
 list-style:none;
}
.nav-link {
 
}
.nav-link a {
 color:#2BA6CB;
 text-decoration:none;
}
/*------------------------------------*\
   Clickable Dropdown
\*------------------------------------*/

body {
 background:url(../img/bg.png);
}
.click-nav {
 margin:100px auto;
 width:200px;
}
.click-nav ul {
 font-weight:900;
}
.click-nav ul li {
 position:relative;
 list-style:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.click-nav ul li ul {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker {
 background:#2284B5;
 color:#FFF;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover,
.click-nav ul .active {
 background:#196F9A;
}
.click-nav img {
 position:absolute;
 top:9px;
 left:12px;
}
.click-nav ul li a {
 transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 display:block;
 padding:8px 10px 8px 40px;
 background:#FFF;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.click-nav ul li a:hover {
 background:#F2F2F2;
}
/* Fallbacks */
.click-nav .no-js ul {
 display:none;
}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Clickable Nav -->
  <div class="click-nav">
   <ul class="no-js">
    <li>
     <a class="clicker">Profile</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign out</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /Clickable Nav -->
```

Comment: Can you put this in a JSFiddle so its easier to edit?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmu4r12y/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this modified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmu4r12y/2/)

I didn't have a time to test it with other elements around it to see how it would behave. If it still gives you trouble consider using .animate instead of the stock slideToggle() and slideUp()

[jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

I changed your markup mainly (instead of ul I chose div so it would stack for you) Set bottom: 100% on absolute ul. Hope this gets you in the right direction.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Clickable Nav -->
        <div class="click-nav">
            <div class="no-js">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="clicker">Profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Clickable Nav -->
```

---UPDATE---
For the scroll of the div you would just add what is different below. Changes reflected in the fiddle:

```
.click-nav div ul {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    max-height: 100px; <--- this (set it to whatever you feel is good.
    overflow-y:scroll; <--- and this (allows div to scroll)
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this it work fine! only problem I'm having is that i need the menu to be able to scroll if larger than the screen, is that possible?

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to show an example of what you just mentioned.

Comment: Hi This works... sort of, is there a way of making it expand to 100% of the content but having a max-height container height of say 80%?

Comment: all i have done is put in max-height 100% instead of px

Comment: You will need to make a fiddle to show me what you're meaning. And you should probably try a few other things than just one property change before you resort to a SO question.

Comment: Ok no probs am putting it together now thanks for your help so far